# ERROR. Access violation writing location

Tags: c++, qt, memory, graph, malloc

I'm trying to write a function which will recursive create a graph.
I have a SQLite DB with all arc and nodes in it.
Here's my function:

```
Node* Graph::addNode(QString id)
{
    QSqlQuery nodeQuery;
    Node* newNode = NULL;
    QString nodeQ = "SELECT n.node_id, a.id AS road_id, a.cost AS cost FROM roads_nodes AS n JOIN roads AS a ON (a.node_from = n.node_id OR a.node_to = n.node_id) WHERE n.node_id = " + id + " ORDER BY n.node_id";
    nodeQuery.exec(nodeQ);
    QSqlRecord nodeRec = nodeQuery.record();
    while(nodeQuery.next())
    {
        newNode = new Node(id);
        vNodes.insert(id, newNode);

        QString arcId = nodeQuery.value(nodeRec.indexOf("road_id")).toString();
        double arcCost = nodeQuery.value(nodeRec.indexOf("cost")).toDouble();
        Arcs* arc = new Arcs(arcId,arcCost, NULL, NULL);

        QString arcQ = "SELECT  \"node_from\", \"node_to\" FROM \"roads\" WHERE id = " + arcId;
        QSqlQuery arcQuery;
        arcQuery.exec(arcQ);
        QSqlRecord arcRec = arcQuery.record();
        
        arcQuery.next();
        QString node_from = arcQuery.value(arcRec.indexOf("node_from")).toString();
        QString node_to = arcQuery.value(arcRec.indexOf("node_to")).toString();
        
        if (vNodes.contains(node_from))
            arc->node_from = vNodes.find(node_from).value();
        else
            arc->node_from = addNode(node_from);//create Node
        
        if(vNodes.contains(node_to))
            arc->node_to = vNodes.find(node_to).value();
        else
            arc->node_to = addNode(node_to);//createNode
        uArcs.insert(arcId,arc);
    }
    return newNode;
}
```

Here's classes which I use:

```
class Arcs
{
public:
    Arcs(QString id, double cost, Node* node_from, Node* node_to ):id(id), cost(cost), node_from(node_from), node_to(node_to){}
    ~Arcs();
    QString id;
    double cost;
    Node* node_from;
    Node* node_to;
};

class Node
{
public:
    Node(QString id):id(id){}
    ~Node();
    QString id;
};
class Graph
{
public:
    Graph();
    ~Graph();
    
    QSqlDatabase *sdb;

    int NodeCount;
    int ArcsCount;

    QHash<QString,Node*> vNodes;
    QHash<QString,Arcs*> uArcs;
    Node* addNode(QString);
};
```

So everything builds successfully without any warnings and so on.
It runs and one time it crashes with such error:

> First-chance exception at 0x7c90e8c5 in roadNetwork.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x011e0f94.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x7c90e8c5 in roadNetwork.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x011e0f94.

To be honest I've tried to read about this issue in the net, but I haven't found any useful tips.
Actually, I've tried to debug this code and it crashes when the virtual memory usage reaches 96-102mb edge. Debugger shows me malloc.h file.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) `Access violation writing location 0xXXXXXXXX` is such a vague error. The first step in debugging is seeing which line/function/library corresponds to that memory address and seeing if it's your issue or an issue with the libraries you're using.

Comment: If it's in `malloc` and your program is allocating a ton of memory when it shouldn't, that indicates a broken loop or some incorrect value passed to `malloc`. I'd start there.

Comment: @Qix I have like 150 000 nodes with 200 000 arcs and I'm trying to build in-memmory graph, so allocating this amount of memory or even more is expected.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about recursive algorithm I use, but it looks like it should working cause it runs over 8000 iterations without error. Moreover, the line which debugger shows when it throws exception is related with 'heap'

Comment: `if (__active_heap == __SYSTEM_HEAP) {
        return HeapAlloc(_crtheap, 0, size ? size : 1);}` malloc.c , size = 66;